# What does this line of erlang code do?

Tags: erlang

Could someone explain to me what this line of erlang code does?

```
[ReportBody|_] = [Body || {<<"val1">>,<<"val2">>,_,_,Body} <- Parts].
```

You can assume the Parts variable to contain the following:

```
[{<<"val1">>,<<"val2">>,
         [{<<"val3">>,
           <<"val4">>},
          {<<"val5">>,<<"val6">>},
          {<<"val7">>,<<"val8">>}],
         [{<<"val9">>,
           [{<<"val10">>,<<"val11">>},{<<"val12">>,<<"val13">>}]},
          {<<"val14">>,<<"val15">>},
          {<<"val16">>,[]}],
         <<"val17">>}]
```

I assume the point of the line of code is to validate if 'val1' and 'val2' exist in 'Parts' and return 'Body'

but is my assumption correct and I would like a detailed explanation of how that line of code works. I am an erlang noob so be gentle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [list comprehension](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/list_comprehensions.html). It

1. requires that `Parts` is a list
2. for every element of this list, checks if it's a five-element tuple where first element is the binary `<<"val1">>` and the second element is `<<"val2">>`.

   1. If yes, the fifth element is called `Body` and added to the result list.
   2. If no, this element is skipped.
3. The list consisting of all `Body` is returned.
4. (Pointed out in comment) `[ReportBody|_] = ...` part binds `ReportBody` to the first element of the list created at 3, dropping the rest.

Comment: ...and then the [ReportBody|_] = ... part binds ReportBody to the first element of the resulting list, dropping the rest.

Comment: @RichardC Oops, skipped the left-hand part, just assumed there was a variable. You are right of course.